# How can we dispatch action from an action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rxjs-observables

I have the following epic file which is having following function,

I need to call action from onUndo but as seen the action.showwarnToast is already dispatch because of which another action is not dispatching

```
export const makeXDiningReservation = createDataEpic({
  name: "makeXDiningReservation",
  apiPath: (action, state) =>
    generatePath("pathToApi", {
      
    }),
  apiOptions: (action, state) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        "Client-Id": "ship",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  },
  successActionCreator: (
    response,
    state,
    action,
    { getIntl, ...rest },
    ...params
  ) => {
   

   if (isDailyPlannerEnabled && eventOverlap) {
      return [
        Actions.throttledScheduleRefresh({ force: true }),
        Actions.diningReservationSuccessOnShip({
          ...action,
          reservationID: response.bookingId,
        }),
        Actions.navigateReplace({
          pathname: generatePath("path", {
            restaurantKey: action.restaurantKey,
          }),
          state: {
            action,
            response: { ...response, reservationID: response.bookingId },
          },
        }),
        Actions.showWarnToastMessage(
          getIntl(state).formatMessage(
            strings.activityOverlapsWithAnotherActivity,
          ),
          {
            color: "warning",
            variant: "standard",
            showUndo: true,
            undoData: response,
            onUndo: (data) => {
              return [
                Actions.navigatePush({
                  pathname: generatePath("/dailyPlanner"),
                }),
                modalActivityActionDrawerActions.setModalState(true),
              ];
            },
          },
        ),
      ];
    } else {
     return [
      Actions.diningReservationSuccessOnShip({
          ...action,
          reservationID: response.bookingId,
      }),
      Actions.navigateReplace({
          pathname: generatePath("/dining/:restaurantKey/confirm", {
            restaurantKey: action.restaurantKey,
          }),
          state: {
            action,
            response: { ...response, reservationID: response.bookingId },
          },
        }),
      ];
    }
  },
  failureActionCreator: (error, state, action) => [
    Actions.epicError(makeXDiningReservation.name, error),
    stopSubmit(action.form, { _error: error }),
  ],
  triggeringActions: [START_DINING_RESERVATION],
  type: REQUEST_TYPE.POST_JSON,
  waitingIdentifier: "DINING_RESERVATION",
});
```

I tried to dispatch like this but it did not work help me to fix it as i am not sure how this will work, eventually i want this to be done from epic side.

```
onUndo: (data) => {
  return [
    Actions.navigatePush({ pathname: generatePath("/dailyPlanner") }),
    modalActivityActionDrawerActions.setModalState(true),
  ];
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The epics don't have free access to the store's dispatch function since that is what the `successActionCreator` and `failureActionCreator` handlers do under the hood, but what I'd suggest is to create a thunk that does. The new Thunk would dispatch the `showWarnToastMessage` action to initiate the toast, and can wrap the undo actions in the `thunkApi.dispatch` call.

Example:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const warnUndoToast = createAsyncThunk(
  "toasts/warnUndoToast",
  ({ message, undoData, undoActions = [] }, { dispatch }) => {
    dispatch(Actions.showWarnToastMessage(
      message,
      {
        color: "warning",
        variant: "standard",
        showUndo: true,
        undoData,
        onUndo: (data) => {
          undoActions.forEach(dispatch);
        },
      },
    ));
  }
);
```

Now instead of dispatching the `Actions.showWarnToastMessage` action directly you will dispatch this new `toastWarnUndo` action in the epic, passing the appropriate props.

```js
export const makeXDiningReservation = createDataEpic({
  ....
  successActionCreator: (
    response,
    state,
    action,
    { getIntl, ...rest },
    ...params
  ) => {
    ...

    if (isDailyPlannerEnabled && eventOverlap) {
      return [
        ...,
        warnUndoToast({
          message: getIntl(state).formatMessage(
            strings.activityOverlapsWithAnotherActivity,
          ),
          undoData: response,
          undoActions: [
            Actions.navigatePush("/dailyPlanner"),
            modalActivityActionDrawerActions.setModalState(true),
          ],
        }),
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        ...
      ];
    }
  },
  ...,
});
```